# blind of an eye vs. blind of one eye

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

> blind of an eye vs. blind of one eye

any difference here?

I think that 'one eye' has more strong sense than 'an eye' in respect of 'single eye'

Comment: We say _blind **in** one eye_.

Comment: "But whatever may be the cause of the blindness , it is fearfully prevalent . Blind men stand in the streets , asking your charity on every corner ; men blind of an eye look out at you from the little ..." from Young Folks' Travels in Asia and Africa - Page 55

Comment: *shaking head* Ok, it's a different common ELL problem -- reading books from 1889 and trying to reason contemporary language usage from them.

Answer (score 1):

The construction "of a(n) [noun]" is fixed. It cannot be "of one [noun]."

It carries a sense of generality, of non-specificity, as well as habitualness. In current usage I can only think of one example: the expression [**of a [time of day]**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/of+an+evening), or sometimes **of a [day of the week]**. The expression means "usually at [time of day] or on a [day of week]," as in the examples given:

> There's nothing better **of a morning** than taking your first sip of coffee.
> There's a soccer club playing at the park if you're ever stuck for something to do **of a morning** in the summertime.

No one speaking today would *ever* say that someone is "blind of an eye," and certainly not "blind of one eye."

Now if you use the more common preposition **in** instead of **of**, as Kate mentioned, then you would generally use "one" instead of "an:"

> Blind men stand in the streets, asking your charity on every corner; men **blind in one eye** look out at you...

This is almost *too* specific, because you are talking about shadowy unspecific men instead of specific men on one specific corner that you met at one specific time. So you could try using the indefinite article:

> Blind men stand in the streets, asking your charity on every corner; men **blind in an eye** look out at you...

But this is really forced usage and does not sound natural. It would be better to reword the phrase entirely, even though it results in some repetition:

> Blind men stand in the streets, asking your charity on every corner; **half-blind** men look out at you...